# Можно ли в C# присвоить создаваемому элементу стиль из словаря ресурсов (файла стиля wpf)?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-стили

Например, я могу программно присвоить цвет заливки, могу создать программно стиль и присвоить его кнопке... Но, можно ли присвоить элементу стиль из словаря ресурсов?

Пример:

```
//Создаётся кнопка
Button b = new Button();
//Присваиваем красный цвет
b.Background = SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
//Можно ли сделать наподобие следующего?
//b.Style = ???
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, в чем проблема? Вы не знаете как получить ресурс или как привести тип?

Comment: Да, к сожалению я не нашла синтаксиса для присваивания стиля. В интернете уже дней пять ищу.

Comment: Что да? Вы не знаете как получить ресурс? Или не знаете как записать значение в свойство стиля кнопки?

Comment: И почему вы не пользуетесь xaml?

Comment: Создаётся массив кнопок на основании групп и блюд меню. Данные берутся из бд на основе запросов и функций.

Comment: Почитайте про ItemsControl